# Python Pandas: zfill for rangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate a running index (eg A00055, A00056...) for a new pandas dataframe. I've tried using `zfill` to pad my string with zeroes but can't seem to get it to work. My code:

```
df.reset_index()
entry_id = 55
df['ref'] = "A" + (df.index + entry_id).map(str) # how do I include zfill(5) here?
print(df['ref']) # output: A55, A56...
```

How can this be done? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: IIUC you can do `df['ref'] = 'A' + pd.Index(np.arange(55, len(df.index) + 1)).astype(str).str.zfill(5)`

Comment: @EdChum thank you so much! Will you like to post your answer as a response so that I can accept it?

Comment: See my answer, my comment was incorrect but the posted answer is now correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a new column by constructing an `Index` object of the correct length, then cast to `str` using [`astype(str)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html#pandas.Index.astype) and then call [`str.zfill(5)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill) and prepend letter 'A':

```
In[62]:
df['ref'] = 'A' + pd.Index(np.arange(entry_id, len(df.index) + entry_id)).astype(str).str.zfill(5)

df

Out[62]: 
           0     ref
0  -0.284920  A00055
1  -0.264921  A00056
2   0.190505  A00057
3  -0.594822  A00058
4   0.501090  A00059
5   0.696072  A00060
6   0.221020  A00061
7   0.565674  A00062
8   2.193464  A00063
9  -0.013642  A00064
10 -0.197993  A00065
11  2.200986  A00066
12 -2.239770  A00067
13  0.976282  A00068
14  0.712886  A00069
15  0.691492  A00070
16  1.112054  A00071
17 -0.536423  A00072
18 -1.551099  A00073
19 -0.679287  A00074
```

Here it constructs an `Index` passing a numpy constructed using `np.arange` which starts at `entry_id` and ends with the length of the existing index plus `entry_id` again. We then cast using `astype` and then use `str.zfill` and prepend 'A'

You can also do this using `RangeIndex` which gives a more compact version:

```
df['ref'] = 'A' + pd.RangeIndex(entry_id, len(df.index) + entry_id).astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```